# Simplifying an HTTP headers parsing

Tags: parsing, http, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

RFC-2616 says that method names are case sensitive.

Trying to simplify the parser routing I'm writing, I've got a question. What could happen if I'll treat these names case insensitive?

There are some statements in the standard, that say that programs *SHOULD* be tolerant. As far as I can see, this is the case for tolerance.

One more question I have, is about leading and trailing spaces and tabs where the standard forbids it. For example, inside the `Request-Line` only spaces allowed.

What if my parser will allow tabs as separators? What about leading spaces before the Request-Line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One rule of thumb says: [Be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle).

So go for it, be as tolerant as you can as long as the input intent is clear, and if it simplifies your parser it's even better.

Answer (score 0):

1) RFC 2616 is obsolete. You should be looking at RFC 7230.

2) If you treat method names case-insensitively, you'll fail once there are two different names that are the same when compared case-insensitively. Unlikely? Yes. Impossible? No.

3) WRT request line parsing: there's absolutely no point in being "liberal" here. In the best case, you'll accept requests that never are made. In the worst case, you'll introduce security holes because you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: 1)I'll try to understan the difference. It's not the immidiate task. 2)You mean GET or Get or get? I don't think the standard will insert such names. 3) 19.3 of rfc-2616 speaks exactly about parsing.

Comment: The RFC does provide for 'method extensions' to be defined (not necessarily by RFC2616+), and does not dictate that they too must be upper-case.  So I agree with Julian that point #2 is relevant.  One could 'be liberal in what you accept' and still give a polite 400 response if a client supplied a `Get` request instead of a `GET` ... that would *both* preserve the integrity of the server's behaviour *and* discourage clients from ignoring the specification.